# How to alias python3 to old path?

Tags: python, macos, bash, python-3.x

Well, I realize it might sound (and be) a silly question, but given that I'm no Bash guru (nor a Python one), I'm a bit lost.

So, here's what I want:

I have Python 2.7 installed at /usr/bin/python
I also have Python 3 at some other location, let's say /X/python3

What's the easiest way to set it up so that when `/usr/bin/python` is invoked, the binary at `/X/python3` runs (with all library dependencies alright)?

**Note:**

a) *I don't want to alias `python` to the new binary. It must be the full path: `/usr/bin/python`. (Backup the old binary and create an alias there? But will the dependencies not break?)*

b) *If it matters at all, the new Python 3 path is: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/*

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is likely to break a lot of 2.x-only software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** even attempt to do this.

`/usr/bin/python` is used by various pieces of *OS X software*, and those pieces of software **will** break the moment you replace that binary with Python 3. The only way out of this is a full OS X re-install. In addition, many 3rd-party services rely on `/usr/bin/python` being the exact version that comes with your specific version of OS X.

Stick with using `python3` for Python 3 software, or use a virtualenv, which lets you swap out the `PATH` so plain `python` is your virtualenv Python of choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the super-fast reply. It sure makes sense. :)